# What is the default mechanism used by scikit-learn algorithms for multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am using scikit-learn to build a multiclass classification model. To this extent, I have tried the RandomForestClassifier, KNeighborsClassifier, LogisticRegression, MultinomialNB, and SVC algorithms. I am satisfied with the generated output. However, I do have a question about the default mechanism used by the algorithms for multiclass classification. I read that [all scikit-learn classifiers are capable of multiclass classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), but I could not find any information about the default mechanism used by the algorithms.

Comment: Some classifiers, like KNeighborsClassifier or RandomForestClassifier are capable of multiclass classification by default. Other, like LogisticRegression, which only capable of saying yes or now, adapt to multiclass by OVR. I do not think such thing as a default "mechanism" exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-vs-the-rest or One-vs-all is the most commonly used and a fair default strategy for multiclass classification algorithms. For each classifier, the class is fitted against all the other classes. Check here for more information https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html

Comment: How your answer would apply to `KNeighborsClassifier` or `RandomForestClassifier`?

Comment: Edited, Thanks! Multiclass in KNN and Random Forest works inherently.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but what does it mean by "works inherently"? I noticed that the scikit-learn documentation mentioned the same, but did not understand what it means.

Comment: It means it supports multiclass natively  do not need any extra manipulation or adaptation like OVR